# How does oneboxing work?

Tags: support, chat, onebox

I'm wondering how oneboxing on chat works.

Do you fetch the data from an API of a site for which oneboxing is implemented or do you scrape the content of that page and extract the desired data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone once asked the chat developer (balpha) this very question...

> [Diago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132480/diago):
> @balpha Very serious question. Is there anywhere that I can read up on how you guys got OneBox to work? Are you using the API and then formatting?
>
> [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha):
> @Diago which oneboxes specifically?
> the SE question, answer and user oneboxes just use the public SE API
> (including the styling information from stackauth)
> wikipedia has a public API too
> amazon has an api (not with anonymous access, though)
> twitter has a public API

[in the Chat Feedback chatroom on MSO, Sep. 10, 2010](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77/conversation/howoneboxeswork)

Comment: [It's all about the APIs, baby...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpMvS1Q1sos)

Comment: I believe the blogs are custom though.  IIRC there was resistance to one boxing the blogs b/c they didn't have an API.